# Splitting 3 bytes into six 4 bits and recombining to two 12 bits

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out a way to split a byte into two (eg. `F8` to `F` and `8`) to be later recombined with other bytes. I read up on bit masking but I still don't quite understand it. This is what I'm trying to do.

`F8 FF FF` - Split the bytes into two. I'll use variables to distinguish the bytes

`u=F`, `v=8`, `w=F`, `x=F`, `y=F`, `z=F`, which are essentially, `uv`, `wx`, `yz`

The end result would be `FF8 FFF` or in variables, `xuv` `yzw`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable `x` with a value known to fit into one byte, you can split it into two [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)s like this:

```
x_lo = x & 0xf;
x_hi = (x >> 4) & 0xf;
```

To combine two [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)s `y_lo` and `y_hi` into one byte you shift and or:

```
y = y_lo | (y_hi << 4);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm dealing with little endian in my program, what are the lo and hi (left or right nibble)?

Comment: If you're working in C, don't worry about the endian-ness.  Let C deal with the internal representation.

Comment: I mean, which one are the left or right nibbles? Is lo the left nibble? or is it the right? Thanks!

Comment: You're asking an irrelevant question.  Big-endianness and little-endinaness refer to how the number is stored in memory.  The operations you need to perform in C refer to the value of the number, not how it's represented in memory.  Keep in mind that the number `0xa0` is always `160`.  The lower nibble (LSB) is 0x0, while the upper nibble (MSB) is 0xa.  This doesn't change if you're on a big-endian or little-endian machine.

Comment: In C the high nibble is always to the left (note the left shift `<<` when joining hi and lo, vs the right-shift `>>` when splitting them).  This is *always* true.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't too familiar with logical operators, I suggest to introduce two little helper functions to encapsulate this stuff:

```
void split_nibbles( unsigned char ch, unsigned char *higherOrder, unsighed char *lowerOrder )
{
  *higherOrder = ch >> 4;
  *lowerOrder = ch & 0x0f;
}

 unsigned char merge_nibbles( unsigned char higherOrder, unsigned char lowerOrder )
 {
   return (higherOrder << 4) | (lowerOrder & 0x0f);
 }
```

You can then write

```
unsigned char bytes[] = { 0xf8, 0xff, 0xff };

unsigned char u, v, w, x, y, z;
split_nibbles( bytes[0], &u, &v );
split_nibbles( bytes[1], &w, &x );
split_nibbles( bytes[2], &y, &z );

bytes[0] = merge_nibbles( x, u );
bytes[1] = merge_nibbles( v, y );
bytes[2] = merge_nibbles( z, w );
```

...which is very close to your description. :-)

Comment: wrapping this in functions is a bit of overkill, don't you think?

Comment: @NathanFellman: If the guy maintaining the code (such as the OP in this case) is clearly not familiar with logical operators in C: no, I don't think moving the logic into functions with descriptive names is overkill.